# How do I make Regex capture only named groups

Tags: c#, regex

According to `Regex` documentation, using `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` makes the Regex only match named groups like `(?<groupName>...)`; but in action it does something a little bit different.

Consider these lines of code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Regex r = new Regex(
        @"(?<code>^(?<l1>[\d]{2})/(?<l2>[\d]{3})/(?<l3>[\d]{2})$|^(?<l1>[\d]{2})/(?<l2>[\d]{3})$|(?<l1>^[\d]{2}$))"
        , RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture
    );
    var x = r.Match("32/123/03");
    r.GetGroupNames().ToList().ForEach(gn => {
        Console.WriteLine("GroupName:{0,5} --> Value: {1}", gn, x.Groups[gn].Success ? x.Groups[gn].Value : "");
    });
}
```

When you run this snippet you'll see the result contains a group named **0** while I don't have a group named 0 in my regex!

```
GroupName:    0 --> Value: 32/123/03  
GroupName: code --> Value: 32/123/03  
GroupName:   l1 --> Value: 32  
GroupName:   l2 --> Value: 123  
GroupName:   l3 --> Value: 03  
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Could somebody please explain this behavior to me?

Comment: The *zeroth group* matches the entire regexp

Comment: @AlexK. Do you mean I just have to ignore the first group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *always* have group 0: that's the entire match. Numbered groups are relative to 1 based on the ordinal position of the opening parenthesis that defines the group. Your regular expression (formatted for clarity):

```
(?<code>
  ^
  (?<l1> [\d]{2} )
  /
  (?<l2> [\d]{3} )
  /
  (?<l3> [\d]{2} )
  $
|
  ^
  (?<l1>[\d]{2})
  /
  (?<l2>[\d]{3})
  $
|
   (?<l1> ^[\d]{2} $ )
)
```

Your expression will backtrack, so you might consider simplifying your regular expression. This is probably clearer and more efficient:

```
static Regex rxCode = new Regex(@"
  ^                    # match start-of-line, followed by
  (?<code>             # a mandatory group ('code'), consisting of
    (?<g1> \d\d )      # - 2 decimal digits ('g1'), followed by
    (                  # - an optional group, consisting of
      /                #   - a literal '/', followed by
      (?<g2> \d\d\d )  #   - 3 decimal digits ('g2'), followed by
      (                #   - an optional group, consisting of
        /              #     - a literal '/', followed by
        (?<g3> \d\d )  #     - 2 decimal digits ('g3')
      )?               #     - END: optional group
    )?                 #   - END: optional group
  )                    # - END: named group ('code'), followed by
  $                    # - end-of-line
" , RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace|RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture );
```

Once you have that, something like this:

```
string[] texts = { "12" , "12/345" , "12/345/67" , } ;

foreach ( string text in texts )
{
  Match m = rxCode.Match( text ) ;
  Console.WriteLine("{0}: match was {1}" , text , m.Success ? "successful" : "NOT successful" ) ;
  if ( m.Success )
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "  code: {0}" , m.Groups["code"].Value ) ;
    Console.WriteLine( "  g1: {0}" , m.Groups["g1"].Value ) ;
    Console.WriteLine( "  g2: {0}" , m.Groups["g2"].Value ) ;
    Console.WriteLine( "  g3: {0}" , m.Groups["g3"].Value ) ;
  }
}
```

produces the expected

```
12: match was successful
  code: 12
  g1: 12
  g2:
  g3:
12/345: match was successful
  code: 12/345
  g1: 12
  g2: 345
  g3:
12/345/67: match was successful
  code: 12/345/67
  g1: 12
  g2: 345
  g3: 67
```

Comment: +1 and thanks for the cleaner version of my regex. I knew It could be expressed in a cleaner manner, but since it worked and I was lazy, I just kept it that way! I'll use your version of regex thankfully and I'll ignore the **0** group.

Answer (score 0):

named **group**

```
^(?<l1>[\d]{2})/(?<l2>[\d]{3})/(?<l3>[\d]{2})$|^(?<l1>[\d]{2})/(?<l2>[\d]{3})$|(?<l1>^[\d]{2}$)
```

[image]

try this (i remove first group from your regex) - [see demo](http://www.systemtextregularexpressions.com/regex.match?p=Xig%2FPGwxPltcZF17Mn0pLyg%2FPGwyPltcZF17M30pLyg%2FPGwzPltcZF17Mn0pJHxeKD88bDE%2BW1xkXXsyfSkvKD88bDI%2BW1xkXXszfSkkfCg%2FPGwxPl5bXGRdezJ9JCk%3D&t=MzIvMTIzLzAz&op=4)

Comment: It's still the same. The **0** group is up there; and on a side note, I need that `code` group to be captured.   
GroupName:    0 --> Value: 32/123/03  
GroupName:   l1 --> Value: 32  
GroupName:   l2 --> Value: 123  
GroupName:   l3 --> Value: 03  
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Pattern "\d+" for text "123" - return array with 1 group = 123.

Pattern "(\d+)" for text "123" - return array with 2 groups = 123 and 123.

Pattern "(?<digit>\d+)" for text "123" - return array with 2 groups too = 123 and 123.

I think this is as it should be.

Comment: `\d+` is not named. `(?<some-name>\d+)` would be named and this acts the same. I think there's something wrong with `GetGroupNames()` method and its interpretation of `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture`.